# SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 324

Tags: node.js, json, npm, jhipster, code-generation

> JHipster: SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 324

for

```
 entity Category {

 }
 relationship ManyToMany {
    Category{parents} to Category{children}
 }
```

Command

```
jhipster import-jdl jhipster-jdl.jh  --force
```

npm 6.4.1

10.13.0 Node.js.

How to fix this?

Comment: Is the JSON valid? You didn't show us a sample of the data which is causing the error. The error suggests you haven't got valid JSON.

Comment: As I know, I have no invalid json, root cause is a mistery for me.

Comment: Well your assertion contradicts your error message. So either your code is reading the wrong thing, or your assertion is incorrect. If you post the data here we can check for you. Or you can use a site like https://jsonlint.com to validate your JSON. Did you you look at position 324 in your data to see what's there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/

> If you do not want to regenerate your entities while importing a JDL, you can use the --json-only flag to skip the entity creation part and create only the json files in .jhipster folder.

```
jhipster import-jdl ./my-jdl-file.jdl --json-only
```

this might help diagnose the problem by letting you see the intermediate json files.

Also, you might want to drop the empty curlies after your entity -- maybe it's confusing jhipster?

Comment: Thanks for accepting! I'm curious, though, what the problem ended up being.